# Angular UI Calendar is not rendering after refreshing the screen

Tags: angularjs, calendar, angular-ui

I am using angular ui calendar to render events, when the page loads application is rendering the calendar properly.

[image]

But when I refresh the screen, events block is not rendering.

[image]

I am using the following code to render the calendar in UI.

Following is my code block.

```
function returnCalendarConfig() {
                            return {
                                calendar: {
                                    height: 500,
                                    editable: false,
                                    displayEventTime: true,
                                    selectable: true,
                                    timeFormat: 'hh:mm A',
                                    stick: true,
                                    defaultView: 'month',
                                    columnFormat: 'dddd',
                                    disableDragging: false,
                                    header: { left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay', center: 'title', right: 'prev,next' },
                                    eventClick: $scope.onEventClick,
                                    dayClick: $scope.onDayClick,
                                    eventRender: $scope.onEventRender
                                }
                            };
    }

    $scope.uiConfig = returnCalendarConfig();

    function getCalendarEvents() {
         var user = commonService.getUser();
         console.log('User Object', user);
         $scope.events = [];
         $timeout(function () {
           applyScope();
         });
         commonService.hideProcessingForSiteDetails(200);
    }

    getCalendarEvents()
```

**getCalendarEvents** method calls at end of the controller.

```
<div class="calendar" data-ng-model="eventSources" calendar="myCalendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar">
</div>
```

Comment: do you see any errors in the console output?

Comment: I didnt see any errors in console. :-(